# JSP application - global variable list using Context.xml Environment tag

Tags: java, jsp, context.xml

Is it possible to have a variable that is string list via the Context.xml file? For example, I'm currently doing this in my context.xml file:

```
    <Environment name="actiontypes" value="INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE,INITIAL" type="java.lang.String" />
```

I read that into a tokenizer and break it down by comma delimited. Anyway I could just store this straight as an array or list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of storing into list for values. But as alternative to tokenizer you can simplify like this

`String[] values = value.split(",")`

Comment: yup, this is exactly what I did. Thanks!